# How to skip from _id with mongoose?

Tags: mongoose

The problem with `.skip(num)` in mongoose is that while adding data to the collection, `skip(num)` could return data existed in previous search. A solution would be skip from _id but I failed to find such option.

So rather than:

`db.collection.find().sort({ _id: -1 }).skip(num).limit(50);`

I like to be able to:

`db.collection.find().sort({ _id: -1 }).skip(_id).limit(50);`

Alternatively if I can get index of `_id` it should be fine too:

```
let res = await db.collection.findOne({_id});
let {index} = res;
db.collection.find().sort({ _id: -1 }).skip(index).limit(50);
```

I use Caffeinated.tech's method and tried:

```
const list = async function({
  end_cursor = ''
} = {}) {
  return await db.discovery.where('_id').gt(end_cursor).sort({ _id: -1 }).limit(50);
}
```

and I got

```
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "" at path "_id" for model "discovery"
```

The correct answer is

```
const list = async function(end_cursor) {
  if (!end_cursor) {
    return await db.discovery.where('_id').sort({ _id: -1 }).limit(50);
  }
  return await db.discovery.where('_id').lt(end_cursor).sort({ _id: -1 }).limit(50);
}
```

Comment: `.skip` only takes a number argument, so that won't work. Are you trying to paginate a collection?

Comment: Yes @Caffeinated.tech

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid duplicates while paginating your query, I would advise using `gt` and `lt` in `where` queries rather than using `skip` and `limit`. This also has the benefit of giving you a constant speed, even when you are thousands of documents down the page (as the `skip` value get's bigger, the query get's slower).

**Here is the general idea:**

I'm listing contacts in an address book. I've loaded and displayed the first 100 contacts, sorting by `createdAt` date ascending and searching for the name `aero`.

1. From your UI / API / whatever send up the id of the last contact currently displayed, and the current sort / search parameters.
2. Load said contact from DB. For example it was `name: "aero 100"` and `createdAt: "01/01/2019"
3. Now construct your query using this contact, so that you are continuing at the next contact after this one. So you will want to search for the same name, and as we are sorting by created at add this sort order **and** search for contacts where `createdAt`
   is greater than the last contact's `createdAt` timestamp.

```
 let lastContact = await Contact.findById(lastId)
 let nextPage = await Contact
   .where({ name: /aero/i })
   .sort({createdAt: 1})
   .gt(createdAt, lastContact.createdAt)
   .limit(100)
   .exec()
```

---

I've published a plugin for mongoose which should make this easier unless you need to do some complex queries / populations etc : [mongoose-fast-pagination](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-fast-pagination).

Comment: @AeroWang The error implies your  `end_cursor` is an empty string - it will have to be a valid bson id